# Как в grunt указать сетевой путь в windows?

Tags: windows, grunt

Хочу чтобы grunt копировал файл на сетевой путь.

```
Допустим Сетевой путь:
dest: '\\mywww\dev\site\view\text.js'

Но вместо этого он создаёт папку 
C:/mywww\dev\site\view
```

---

Не работает это везде:
grunt-contrib-concat
grunt-contrib-uglify
работают хорошо

а вот 
grunt-contrib-copy

Пишет:

Warning: Unable to create directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rrr\C:" (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.

при том что дирректорию он создает если её нет.
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rrr

настройка:

```
copy: {
  default: {
    expand: true,

    src: ['C:/inetpub/wwwroot/** '],
    dest: 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/rrr',
  },
},
```

Comment: Попробуйте поставить прямые слешы: `dest: '//mywww/dev/site/view/text.js'`

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить прямые слешы: `dest: '//mywww/dev/site/view/text.js'`

---

По второй части вопроса: копирование при использовании в `src` абсолютного пути почти всегда работает не так, как нужно. Необходимо задавать параметр `cwd`, а в `src` указывать путь относительно пути в `cwd`:

```
copy: {
  default: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot',
    src: ['./**'],
    dest: 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/rrr',
  },
},
```

P.S. Копирование идет в подкаталог каталога-источника, поэтому при каждом последующем запуске grunt у вас будут создаваться все новые и новые файлы. Исключите файлы назначения из источника: `src: ['./**', '!./rrr/**']`.